# Mingw32 cross compile with c++11

Tags: c++11, mingw, cross-compiling

How can I cross compile on Linux for Windows with code that uses C++11 features? So far I've attempted the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class foo
{
    public:
        const char* getstr() { return "hello world"; }
};

int main()
{
  printf("Hello, World!\n");

  foo f;
  f.getstr();
  auto q = f.getstr();
  return 0;
}
```

This fails to build with:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ cpp11_test.cpp 
cpp11_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cpp11_test.cpp:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘q’ with no type
cpp11_test.cpp:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’
```

No problem I thought, I just need the `-std=c++11` option:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ cpp11_test.cpp -std=c++11
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

Still no luck, --version output is:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ --version
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ (GCC) 4.2.1-sjlj (mingw32-2)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is there another option to make this work? Or a new version? How would I get a new version if its not in the package manager, would I have to build a newer compiler from source using the host OS'es compiler?

Comment: Your compiler is outdated.

Comment: `Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.` should tell you that your compiler will have at best very poor support for C++11.

Comment: Hmmm good point, how could I get an updated i586-mingw32msvc-g++?

Comment: @paulm The package manager for your Linux distribution can likely download and install a more recent version, the exact mechanisms will depend on what exact distro you are using.

Comment: @paulm: You can use c++11 supported online compiler for your programs at : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: @Casey I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 - I believe I have the most recent version of the package from these repos

Comment: You probably need to use the mingw-w64 packages. Since they are at version 4.6.3 (rather old still), you'll need to use -std=c++0x. I don't use ubuntu so I'm not sure how you should install those packages. Maybe [this link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/g++-mingw-w64-i686/) will help.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out later and see what happens

Comment: Looks like this might be the one I want: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/